# CSS : Animation / Translation effect when a color is applied to a grey line

Tags: css, jquery-animate, css-animations

Simple question : I want to color a line that is initially black to green color. whenever i apply green color it gets applied immediately to while line buti want the green color to apply from left to right slowly. how can i get this effect.[image]

```
<div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1" id="dev_resend_request">
      <div class="settingiconblue">
          <div class="settingdivblue">
              <a href="">
                  <span class="fa-stack fa-2x">
                      <i class="fa fa-refresh" style="color:green"></i>
                  </span>
              </a>
          </div>
          <p class="box-title">Resend Request</p>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: where is your code..!

Comment: when do you apply this class? on click ? on hover ? why would you want to use jquery to apply a class when you can use just css to achieve what you want ? see Rohit's answer below . also...edit the question with your code and what you have tried

Comment: i have added my code and i apply this class on click of a button .

Comment: @ Kirk Beard, LGSon, Deepak Yadav, Mohammad Usman, gnat  : please dont close issue , i am unable to post new questions. i have edited the question as requested by the website. please validate and reopen the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have made the same effect on mouse `hover`. You can change it according to your code's situation or you can use it with `jQuery`.

```css
.line {width: 100%; height: 10px; background: black; position: relative;}
.line:before {content: ""; background: green; width: 0px; height: 100%; transition: all 2s ease-in-out; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px;}
.line:hover:before {width: 100%;}
```

```html
<div class="line"></div>
```

This code will make effect on `click` event...

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
      $('.line').on('click', function(){
       $('.line-green').css('width', '100%');
      });
});
```

```css
.line {width: 100%; height: 10px; background: black; position: relative;}
.line-green {position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; height: 100%; width: 0px; background: green; transition: all 2s linear;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="line">
 <div class="line-green"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: looks good. but the problem is that i need it when a class called green is applied to that line.

Comment: once the class is applied. the line should turn green from left to right. and stay green. No hover effect

Comment: line is initally black and turns green on click

Comment: Okay..! I will change my answer according to you.